# Changing CSS with Javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I have a site that is covered by a div. I want to make the div disappear when someone enters the correct password. I validate the form with Javascript and successfully change the `CSS` of that div from `display:block` to `display:none`, but immediately after the display property has been changed it changes back to default again. I want to have it so the display of `#overlay` is forever set to none if the password is correct.

The form.

```
<form id="overlay-form" name="overlay-form" method="post" onsubmit="validateForm();">
<input id="overlay-password" name="overlay-password" type="password">
<input type="submit" id="overlay-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript.

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["overlay-form"]["overlay-password"].value;
            if (x == "password") {
                document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
            }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the page to refresh or..? In this way, the page will reload due to the form submit... The form is coming back to the initial state because you actually are refreshing the page by **submitting** the form, I think you don't want to submit it, but you just want to use a regular button. http://jsfiddle.net/zth0vkzo/ <-- This is what you're looking for, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a form submit does a reload of the page (or redirects to the action url if given). If you want to prevent this default behaviour, add this to your javascript:

```
function validateForm(event) { // pass in the event as a parameter, this is the form submit

    var x = document.forms["overlay-form"]["overlay-password"].value;
        if (x == "password") {
            document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behaviour here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press the submit button, the page reloads, and the div is visible again. You need a regular button, not a submit button. `<input type="button">` makes a normal button that doesn't submit the form.

You must not write the password to the javascript, because everyone can see it!

Comment: But if i don't submit the form how will I be able to validate the form?

Comment: And i'm using Javascript for now because it it easy to change css with js

Comment: Remove `onsubmit="validateForm();"` from the form tag, and add `onclick="validateForm();"` to the button.